# Should [BAM] be burned?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

**Q1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

The wiki has,

> Business Activity Monitoring are tools from various vendors that allow for real-time insight into their operational data. The key differentiator between a BAM dashboard and a traditional Business Intelligence dashboard is the real-time factor.
>
> 1. Microsoft BizTalk provides a BAM product
> 2. WSO2 has a BAM product

There are [188 questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam) with [bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam)

Of these

1. [23 also tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam+biztalk) with [biztalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk)
2. [139 also tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam+wso2) with [wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2) when there is a [wso2bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2bam) tag available ([also 3 tagged with wso2esb without a wso2 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam+wso2esb+-wso2))
3. [2 also tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam+samtools) with [samtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samtools)
4. [21 with none of the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam+-samtools+-biztalk+-wso2+-wso2esb)

**A1. No it is a rather ambiguous**

**Q2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

**A2. There may be some coding involved with some**

**Q3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

**A3. More specific tags would be more meaningful**

**Q4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

**A4. No**

**Proposal:**

1. That a biztalk-bam tag be created and the bam for biztalk questions retagged to that
2. That bam questions for wso2 be retagged to wso2bam
3. Create a samtools-bam and retag those
4. Clean up the remainder so BAM can burn.

Comment: Sounds like a buzzword to me.  Let's nuke it.

Comment: Your second point is non disputabled. There are [129 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam+wso2+-wso2bam) tagged with both bam and wso2 but not wso2bam. I'll start to edit/flag/etc.

Comment: Should we at the same time look at burninating cep? Added a question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294344/burninate-cep

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yep, like esb. Both have the same problem :)

Comment: @Docteur Yeah, noticed that also. Lots to do! :)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Good luck! It appears that I shouldn't help until I have 2k rep. :/

Comment: @Docteur Yeah, people don't really like having retagging in the edit approve queue, so better leave it for 2k+ people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retag of [bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bam) to [biztalk-bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-bam) complete.

Retag to [wso2bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2bam) complete.

BAM with SAMTools or [bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics) is actually a reference to binary version of the SAM file (nothing to do with Business Activity Monitoring).  Removed tag.

BAM with Oracle retag to new tag [oracle-bam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-bam) complete

Comment: I've done a few dozen of these. I will continue tonight if not doen by then! :-)

Comment: I'm helping too!~

Comment: So we are down to 4 questions now.  Two are closed (one has only BAM as a tag).  And the other two probably should be.  How can we clean up these last 4?