# Burninate [cep]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request, retag-request

While [burninating bam tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293460/should-bam-be-burned), noticed there is also [cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep), which is a bit ambiguous.

**Q1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

The wiki:

> Complex event processing (CEP) consists of high-speed processing of many events across all the layers of an organization, identifying the most meaningful events within the event cloud, analyzing their impact, and taking subsequent action in real time.

There are [210 questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep) with [cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep)

Of these

1. [98 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+wso2) with [wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2)
2. [56 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+esper) with [esper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esper)
3. [36 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+siddhi) with [siddhi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/siddhi)
4. [18 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+drools) with [drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drools)
5. [11 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+streaminsight) with [streaminsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streaminsight)
6. [5 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+oracle) with [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
7. [3 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+nesper) with [nesper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nesper)
8. [2 tagged also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+fiware) with [fiware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiware)
9. [26 not tagged with any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep+-wso2+-esper+-fiware+-siddhi+-drools+-streaminsight+-nesper+-oracle)

A1. No it is a rather ambiguous, it doesn't clearly relate to a single platform

**Q2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

A2. The 26 questions which are not tagged with any of those tags seem to be mostly about configuring, choosing a CEP product etc, so they may even be off-topic

**Q3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

A3. More specific tags would be more meaningful, since the operations done with them are very different based on the platform

**Q4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

A4. Theoretically, yes, but since the platforms differ, in reality no.

**Proposal:**

1. wso2 + cep -> wso2cep
2. drools + cep -> drools-fusion
3. esper, nesper, siddhi, streaminsight are cep platforms, so remove cep tag from these

This would eliminate vast majority of the cep tag.

The only question is what to do with the general questions, like eclipse plugins and Oracle tools? In my eyes they are even off-topic, since they are about tools and not programming per se. Remove cep tag and let it burn?

Answer (score 7):

Complex event processing is a thing. These questions are not well tagged by having only the name of a product or tool, or a combination of a product name and 'CEP'. Clearly it would be easy to have a question which relates to complex event processing, and which is about general concepts, independent of a specific database or tool. There are certainly people who are generally interested in questions about CEP, or generally knowledgeable about how to solve CEP problems, and might be interested in responding to questions on this tag.

Your answers to the four questions seem to frankly be "yes, unless you think that two different pieces of software cannot share a concept", "yes, except maybe for 'most' of a small subset", "yes, but" and "yes", in that order.

You are trying to make an argument that for example 'sql' should not be a tag, because

1. It is ambiguous, since more than one different databases exist.
2. 'sql' in the context of a question about SQL Server **does not mean the same thing** as 'sql' in the context of a question about MySQL. This is not an accurate claim.

The presence of some bad questions does not mean that a tag should be removed. These questions should be dealt with, independently of the drive to remove dubious tags.

Answer (score 4):

While I've never heard of this acronym, the tag wiki seems to give a clear description of it, and appears to be unambiguous.  The fact that it does not apply to a single platform is irrelevant.  Would you say multi-threading doesn't deserve a tag because it isn't single platform?

I'd also say its on topic for this site-  it is a programming concept.

You seem to think since its a high level concept that has particular implementations it isn't tag worthy.  That's not the case.